# Assigning Value To Variable Within Subscribe Method is not set outside of the subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular5

How to Access Value Outside Subscribe Method

```js
public ttl_count = 0;
ngOnInit() {
    this.MacService.getAllCouseCount().subscribe((res)=> {
        this.ttl_count = res['count']
    });
}
```

Whenever I `console.log(this.ttl_count)` within the subscribe function I get the right result but whenever I log it outside the subscribe function I get 0

Comment: Because using `subscribe` makes the code asynchronous. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039025/angular-2-value-from-service-not-available-outside-subscribe-function?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this.MacService.getAllCouseCount().subscribe` method is asynchronous and `console.log(this.ttl_count)` outside subscribe method executes first until you get the response from `this.MacService.getAllCouseCount()`

you could use async-await or convert `this.MacService.getAllCouseCount()` this to a promise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known question.
This is because of all the behavior of observable & subscribe is async, therefore it will have the value just after the subscription. So the functions should be fired after the sub.

```
public ttl_count=0;

ngOnInit()
{
  this.MacService.getAllCouseCount().subscribe((res)=>
   {
       this.ttl_count=res['count']; // <-- just here it gets the value.
       console.log(this.ttl_count); // <-- it has value, it happend after!

       this.example();
   });
  console.log(this.ttl_count); // <-- no value, it happend before.
}  

public example(): void 
{
    console.log(this.ttl_count); // <-- it has value here.
}
```